# BsTable with different Row Background

Tags: razor, asp.net-core-mvc

Bootstrap 4 provides the ability to have different table row background colors.
Right now I am checking a condition in my MVC Index View and choose the background of this row.

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
   @if(item.condition1)
   {
       <tr class="table-success">
           <td></td>
       </tr>
   }
   else if(item.condidtion2)
   {
       <tr class="table-warning">
           <td></td>
       </tr>
   }
   else
   {
       <tr class="table-danger">
           <td></td>
       </tr>
   }
```

This works without problems, but it is not really good in a long term aspect.
If you have lots of  elements in each row you have lots of duplicate code.With more condictions it gets worse. Is there a better way to avoid duplicate code? If I want to change elements, I have to edit or add  elements for every row. The usual problems with code redundancy.
I tried to have only a single  without closing tags for each condition and after those the  and  but this gives compiler errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the ternary conditional operator(?:) in `tr`,x?y:z.It works like:

```
if(x)
{
return y;
}
else
{
return z;
}
```

Here is a demo worked:

```
public class Item
    {
        public bool Condition1 { get; set; }
        public bool Condition2 { get; set; }
        public bool Condition3 { get; set; }
    }
```

Controller:

```
public IActionResult TestItem()
        {
            Item item1 = new Item { Condition1 = false, Condition2 = false, Condition3 = true };
            Item item2 = new Item { Condition1 = false, Condition2 = true, Condition3 = false };
            Item item3 = new Item { Condition1 = true, Condition2 = false, Condition3 = false };
            Item item4 = new Item { Condition1 = false, Condition2 = false, Condition3 = false };
            List<Item> l = new List<Item> { item1, item2, item3,item4 };
            return View(l);
        }
```

View:

```
<table>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr @(item.Condition1 ? "class=table-success" : item.Condition2?"class=table-warning":item.Condition3?"class=table-danger":"")>

        <td>TestItem</td>

    </tr>
      
    }
</table>
```

result:
[image]